# Running Cypress in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cypress, google-cloud-build

I need to run cypress e2e tests in Google Cloud Build. I get the error that I need to install cypresses [dependencies](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Advanced-setup) when I just run `id: End to End Test`. So, I attempted to download the dependencies but this occurs:

```
E: Unable to locate package libasound2'
E: Unable to locate package libxss1
E: Unable to locate package libnss3
E: Unable to locate package libgconf-2-4
E: Unable to locate package libnotify-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgtk2.0-0'
E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-0
E: Unable to locate package xvfb
Reading state information...
Building dependency tree...
Reading package lists...
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
Digest: sha256:eb70667a801686f914408558660da753cde27192cd036148e58258819b927395
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Pulling image: ubuntu
```

How can I run cypress in Google Cloud Build?

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
    ... npm setup ...
    - name: 'ubuntu'
      id: Install Cypress Dependencies
      args:
          [
              'apt-get',
              'install',
              'xvfb',
              'libgtk2.0-0',
              'libnotify-dev',
              'libgconf-2-4',
              'libnss3',
              'libxss1',
              libasound2',
          ]
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:current'
      id: End to End Test
      args: ['run', 'e2e:gcb']
```

Answer (score 5):

So the issue with what you have is that steps are meant to be isolated from one another. running `apt-get update` works but does not persist when you attempt to `apt-get` install the required dependencies. Only data in the project directory (which defaults to `/workspace`) is persisted between steps.

Rather than trying to figure out a workaround with that, I was able to successfully get Cypress to run in Google Cloud Build by using the [Cypress Docker image](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/). One thing to note is that you will also have to cache the Cypress install inside the `workspace` folder during the `npm install` step. You'll also probably want to add the `.tmp` directory to your `.gcloudignore`

```
  - name: node
    id: Install Dependencies
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ['install']
    env:
      - 'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/workspace/.tmp/Cypress'
```

And then you can run the tests like so

```
  - name: docker
    id: Run E2Es
    args:
      [
        'run',
        '--workdir',
        '/e2e',
        '--volume',
        '/workspace:/e2e',
        '--env',
        'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/e2e/.tmp/Cypress',
        '--ipc',
        'host',
        'cypress/included:3.2.0'
      ]
```

Or, if you want to run a custom command rather than the default `cypress run`, you can do

```
  - name: docker
    id: Run E2Es
    args:
      [
        'run',
        '--entrypoint',
        'yarn',
        '--workdir',
        '/e2e',
        '--volume',
        '/workspace:/e2e',
        '--env',
        'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/e2e/.tmp/Cypress',
        '--ipc',
        'host',
        'cypress/included:3.2.0',
        'e2e',
      ]
```

Let's break this down....

- `name: docker` tells Cloud Build to use the [Docker Cloud Builder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders#supported_builder_images_provided_by)
- `--workdir /e2e` tells docker to use a `/e2e` directory in the container during the run
- `--volume /workspace:/e2e` points the `/e2e` working directory used by docker to the `/workspace` working directory used by cloud build
- `--env CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/e2e/.tmp/Cypress` tells cypress to point at `/e2e/.tmp/Cypress` for the Cypress cache.
- `--ipc host` fixes issues with Cypress crashing during the test run
- `cypress/included:3.2.0` the Cypress Docker image which includes cypress and the browsers

And if you are running your own script:

- `--entrypoint yarn` overrides the default entrypoint in the `cypress/included` Dockerfile (which, remember, is `cypress run`)
- `e2e` is the script you'd like to run to run e2es

Hope this helps! I spent over a week trying to get this to work so I figured I'd help out anyone else facing the same issue :)

Comment: If someone else can replicate this response I’ll mark it as the answer. I have moved past the above project so I am not able to verify this answer myself. Thank you for the write up!

Answer (score 1):

running cypress in google cloud build works (now) fine with:

```
steps:
  # install dependencies
  - id: install-dependencies
    name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ['install']
    env:
    - 'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/workspace/.tmp/Cypress'

  # run cypress
  - id: run-cypress
    name: cypress/included:7.0.1
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ['run', 'vue-cli-service', 'test:e2e', '--headless']
    env:
    - 'CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/workspace/.tmp/Cypress'
options:
  machineType: 'E2_HIGHCPU_8'
```

Note:

- There is **no** `cypress/included:latest` tag, therefore the tag needs to be kept updated
- uses `E2_HIGHCPU_8` machine type, as the default only provides 1 vCPU and 4GB
- Example args are for vue, but anything supported by the `cypress/included` image can be executed

Comment: Note that use of `E2_HIGHCPU_8` is outside of the Google free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with GCB, but you probably need to do `apt-get update` before you can do `apt-get install`, try:

```
steps:
    ... npm setup ...
    - name: 'ubuntu'
      id: Update apt index
      args:
          [
              'apt-get',
              'update',
          ]
    - name: 'ubuntu'
      id: Install Cypress Dependencies
      args:
          [
              'apt-get',
              'install',
              'xvfb',
              'libgtk2.0-0',
              'libnotify-dev',
              'libgconf-2-4',
              'libnss3',
              'libxss1',
              'libasound2',
          ]
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:current'
      id: End to End Test
      args: ['run', 'e2e:gcb']
```

Also, note that you have a typo on `libasound2'` :)